# Generate JavaDoc for inherited methods which are not overridden

Tags: java, eclipse, inheritance, javadoc

I have a class (for example) "OverridenArrayList". Which overrides a few methods of a normal ArrayList.
Now I want to generate a Javadoc which should contains the methods I changed of course and a few other important methods which are NOT overridden (And also not generated in the exported JavaDoc). For example the "size()" method.

Of course I could override the method like this

```
@Override
public int size() {
    return super.size();
}
```

And it would be generated too. But this would be sometimes a bit annoying if there are more than e.g. 10 important methods and I have to write these 10 methods in every subclass I create.

It would be nice if someone could tell me another easier way to tell Eclispe that it should generate these "important" methods to all subclasses, too.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish by overriding a method and just calling super.method()? If you're not providing any additional functionality, why do you want to generate/override them?

Comment: I tried to tell the JavaDoc-Generator to generate the documentaion of the size() method also in this class when I'm exporting the JavaDoc. The question is not about any functionality, only about the JavaDoc :)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think what you are trying to accomplish is possible. How should JavaDoc know the methods that you want to include in your documentation? However by default there will be a list in your class' JavaDoc with **all** inherited methods.

To give the user of your class some hints on methods that you consider to be important, you may of course use the `@see` or `@link` JavaDoc tags to create links to the documentation of the inherited methods.

Comment: thx, you're the only one until now who understood my problem :D

Comment: I meant that maybe I could tell java or Eclipse which methods should be inculed and which not. But ok, I will try live without this feature :D

Answer (score 0):

JavaDoc will be generated regardless of method is overriden or not. You need to have the proper comment format for the methods where you need the javadoc to generate it.

Refer below:
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_documentation.htm

Add thie above your methods to get JavaDoc:

```
/** documentation */
```

Hope i understood your question correctly :)

Comment: I know how to make a JavaDoc :D But I want that it generates the overridden doc without an overridden method :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `{@inheritDoc}` [tag](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javadoc.html#@inheritDoc).

Do not forget to use `-sourcepath` and have the sources available. In this case, you want to copy the Javadoc comments from a JDK library class. This means you need to have JDK sources (src.zip) downloaded and exploded somewhere. I am not sure how to do this on Eclipse, but if you were to do this on command line, you'd do:

1. Create your class that extends `ArrayList`, say `FooList.java`.
2. `javadoc -sourcepath jdk-sources -d doc FooList.java`.

Here's an example:

```
    public class FooList<T> extends ArrayList<T> {

    /** This method is a new method, so javadoc should be visible */
    public void newMethod() {

    }

    /** Javadoc is overloaded, since I rewrote the javadoc comments*/
    @Override
    public int size() {
        return super.size();
    }


/** <p>
 * This is an overloaded method, so javadoc should be visible
 *  </p>
 *  {@inheritDoc}
 * @return
 * {@inheritDoc}
 * */
    @Override
        public T get(int index) {
            System.out.println(" foo ....");
            return super.get(index);
        }
}
```

**In Intellij**, I see the Javadoc for the `get` method (on ^J) as follows:

[image]

Note the use of `{@inheritDoc}` in both main body and `@return`.

Comment: OK, but I asked if it's possible to generate it into the exported JavaDoc without writing the size() method in the "FooList"-class :D

Comment: You misunderstand. If you are extending another class and are not overriding the implementations of public/protected methods, what's the point of copying the javadoc _by default_? One can always go to the super class and read the javadoc. I thought you wanted to _purposely_ copy the documentation.

Comment: But I'm talking about an exported JavaDoc, and not about the "previewed infobubbles which contains the doc" or something like this :D